# WPF: how to make async call in UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml

I have a button in xaml whose mouseclick is connected to a delegate command. In delegate command, I am calling another method which creates bit map and saves it to a pdf. This method takes few seconds(usually more than 10 seconds) during which the app goes to Not responding state where the UI is not accessible. During which time I wanted to show some animation which is already defined in xaml. But showing it just before calling the time-taking-function and hiding it afterwards doesnt work. It shows up at the end of time-taking-function execution if i dont use different thread.

So, I tried using creating a different thread and calling this time taking function. Animation loads fine But the function actually needs to access some UI objects in UI thread. It results in this exception:
"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Is there a way to achieve it ? i.e., to show the animation during this function execution ?

Some code snippet:

```
private void OnExportPDFCommand()
    {
        PanelLoading = true;  // Flag to show animation
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                CreatePDF();  //time-taking-function
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => PanelLoading = false);
            });
    }
```

Please explain with a small example. I am new to WPF. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You can make `OnExportPDFCommand` an `async` method and `await` the `Task` you start:

```
private async void OnExportPDFCommand()
{
    PanelLoading = true;  // Flag to show animation
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
            CreatePDF();  //time-taking-function
    });
    PanelLoading = false; // stop animation
}
```

The compiler turns this into a state machine. The control flow is returned to the caller (the UI) at the `await` keyword. When the `Task` finishes, execution is eventually resumed at the next statement `PanelLoading = false`.

This way, the call to `PanelLoading` is *in* the UI thread again and no exception should be raised.

If you need to make other calls to the UI (inside `CreatePDF`) you can use `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(...)` to invoke these calls on the UI thread.

---

As a side note: you might want to disable the button that starts this at the beginning of `OnExportPDFCommand()` and enable it again at the end. This way you can avoid to start the operation multiple times and get confused with your animation.

Comment: @vinmm As an aside. The `bool PanelLoading` pattern is probably not a good idea. If you invoke the `OnExportPDFCommand()` multiple times, you could have unexpected behavior regarding the `PanelLoading` flag. It might be better to replace the `bool PanelLoading` with an int, which you can use `Interlocked.Increment` and `Interlocked.Decrement` with.

Comment: @Rene Vogt: I have the flag in place already for what you mentioned as side note. Thanks. But I still have problem. The createPDF function has many reference back to UI objects(infact in many places) as its a heavy operation dealing with bitmap and files. So to add Invoke to all many places would be difficult. Is there any better alternative to this ?? & Thanks for the snippet.

Comment: @vinmm I personally like the [`IProgress<T>´](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx) approach, but that means to change all those places, too. If you access the UI directly from that method, I can't think of a solution that won't need to change all those places.

Comment: @vinmm a better link for `Progress<T>`: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html

Comment: Yep. Thats the issue. My function uses many things from UI. :(. Thanks for all the info you gave.

Comment: @Rene Vogt: Do you thing I can do something by using async and await features but by not sending the time-taking-function to different Task(while having access to UI objects) ??

Comment: @vinmm sorry, don't know how. if the time consuming method is running in the ui thread, the ui will be blocked. And if it's not on the ui thread, you'll need some kind of invoke mechanism for the ui access from this method.