# How can you prevent UI in C# WPF from hanging?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a C# script that connects to remote server and display all members of a local group. The script is running but it hangs upon searching/connecting to the server.

I have the following required fields in the WPF:

1. ServerList (combobox)
2. UserAccess (textbox multiline)
3. DataGridResult (DataGrid for output)

Here's my async/await script, but still hangs:

```
private async void ButtonRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (UserAccess.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("What Access are we going to display?");
        return;
    }

    string[] separate = new string[] { "\r\n" };
    string[] strServers = ServerList.Text.Split(separate, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    if (strServers == null || ServerList.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There are no Servers Defined!");
        return;
    }

    int strServersCount = ServerList.LineCount;

    DataTable temptable = new DataTable();
    temptable.Columns.Add("Server");
    temptable.Columns.Add("Comments");

    ButtonRun.IsEnabled = false;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
            {
                for (var i = 0; i <= strServersCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        DirectoryEntry directoryServers = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + strServers[i] + ",computer");
                        DirectoryEntry directoryGroup = directoryServers.Children.Find(UserAccess.Text + ",group");
                        object members = directoryGroup.Invoke("members", null);

                        foreach (object GroupMember in (IEnumerable)members)
                        {
                            DirectoryEntry directoryMember = new DirectoryEntry(GroupMember);
                            Console.WriteLine(directoryMember.Name + " | " + directoryMember.Path);
                            temptable.Rows.Add(strServers[i], directoryMember.Name + " | " + directoryMember.Path);
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        temptable.Rows.Add(strServers[i], "Error: " + ex.InnerException + " | " + ex.Message);
                    }
                    DataGridResult.ItemsSource = temptable.DefaultView;
                    ButtonRun.IsEnabled = true;
                }
            }));
    });
}
```

Comment: where is `async/await`? where it hands?

Comment: open google and write: "wpf asynchronous ui responsive". You'll find alot on async/await and Tasks/etc, like minimalistic usable examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37829181/717732 or whole 'tutorials' like https://stephenhaunts.com/2014/10/14/using-async-and-await-to-update-the-ui-thread/

Comment: ah, note that async/await/Tasks are **not the only way** to not-freeze your UI, but most probably they ae easiest/safest to learn.

Comment: `Task.Run(() =>  { Dispatcher.Invoke(... everything) }` The Invoke bends all your work back to the main thread immediately. The Task.Run is canceled out.

Comment: You mark a question as solved on Stack Overflow by accepting an answer (as you have done, with the checkmark). You don't need to edit the title or anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An attempt to fix this, untested:

```
    string userAccessText = UserAccess.Text;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
        //        {
                    for (var i = 0; i <= strServersCount - 1; i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            DirectoryEntry directoryServers = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + strServers[i] + ",computer");
                            DirectoryEntry directoryGroup = directoryServers.Children.Find(userAccessText + ",group");
                            object members = directoryGroup.Invoke("members", null);

                            foreach (object GroupMember in (IEnumerable)members)
                            {
                                DirectoryEntry directoryMember = new DirectoryEntry(GroupMember);
                                Console.WriteLine(directoryMember.Name + " | " + directoryMember.Path);
                                temptable.Rows.Add(strServers[i], directoryMember.Name + " | " + directoryMember.Path);
                            }

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            temptable.Rows.Add(strServers[i], "Error: " + ex.InnerException + " | " + ex.Message);
                        }
                      //  DataGridResult.ItemsSource = temptable.DefaultView;
                     //   ButtonRun.IsEnabled = true;
                    }
           //     }));  // End of Invoke
    });  

    DataGridResult.ItemsSource = temptable.DefaultView;
    ButtonRun.IsEnabled = true;
```

The basic idea is to put all the non-GUI stuff inside the Task, and then consume the data in the async OnClick method after awaiting that Task.

Comment: I did try you script but failed with error "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Comment: On which line??

Comment: This part.. DirectoryEntry directoryGroup = directoryServers.Children.Find(UserAccess.Text + ",group");

Comment: I missed that, put `UserAccess.Text` in a string variable _before_ the Task.Run. Reading a textbox falls under "GUI stuff".